# Conditional Vuelidate Validator

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, vuelidate

I'm REALLY not understanding the vuelidate custom validation.
It's not the first time i have this problem, and i gave up every time and hacked it together in a different way.
but i want to do it right from now on.

i want to have a conditional validator that checks for (in this case) minValue(0) or minValue(0.01), depending on other things on the page.

The built-in "constructor-type" Validators seem not to work if they're not used in exactly this manner: `minValue: minValue(x)`

i just can't even after days of trying, figure out how this is supposed to work.

```
// this works no problem, but is not conditional

dividend_interest: {
    minValue: minValue(0)
}
```

```
// tried this, doesn't work

dividend_interest: {
    minValue: this.bond.term_length === 0 ? minValue(0) : minValue(0.01),
}
```

```
// same with this

dividend_interest: {
    minValue: function(val) {
        return this.bond.term_length === 0 ? minValue(0) : minValue(0.01)
    },
}
```

```
// also no success with this one

dividend_interest: {
          minValue: minValue(this.bond.term_length === 0 ? 0 : 0.01),
}
```

How can it be so hard to do this?

the official docs https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-optional-validator suggest an external const which returns true or false.
while this does kind of work, it doesn't help me, because it ONLY returns true or false, and not params (to generate error messages from etc), and i can't access runtime properties of my vue instance (like this.bond.term_length in this case).

### so how can i write a simple conditional custom vuelidate validator that uses the minValue (or any other) constructor?

Comment: I think [maybe this will help you](https://jsfiddle.net/thmskLp9/)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy this seems to work... interesting... why didn't it work the way i did it? what is different if you `return` this whole thing? i'm trying to understand. thank you anyways, seems like it was this little thing that solved my problem for now